# pip won't find system package on a custom location

Tags: centos, non-root-user, pip

I am working remotely on a CentOS system via bash with an account without administrator privileges and I need to install the Python package matplotlib.

I can do this using `pip install -t target/directory` and `virtualenv`,
however matplotlib requires a system package, `freetype`, that I cannot install, thus it complains as following:

```
* The following required packages can not be built:

                        * freetype
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_niccolo/matplotlib
```

I therefore dowloaded the source code of freetype and ran "make" and "make install". Of course I had to do this on user level to custom folders, which I tried to include on the bash $PATH.

Now, when I run pip install matplotlib, it seems unaware of my custom freetype installation and it keeps complaining with the same error as before.

How can I make pip understand where to look for freetype?